# Which groups are a non-trivial semidirect product of abelian groups?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups, semidirect-product

> **Fact 1 (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425062/592365) MSE post):** The semidirect product $G \rtimes H$ is abelian iff $G$ is abelian, $H$ is abelian, and the semidirect product is trivial (and thus is just a product.)

So we may ask, *which nonabelian groups are nontrivial semidirect products of two abelian groups?*

The general problem of understanding how groups decompose under the semidirect product is hard. The only related theorem I know of is the [Schur-Zassenhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem). I do not think it directly gives any answers to my question.

I am interested in and am here to ask for partial results or observations related to my question. E.g., can any reasonable restrictions on our non-abelian group rule it out as a SDP of abelian groups?

I know of no such classification results and am unable to find any online. Keith Conrad has [some notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/semidirect-product.pdf) discussing when a group decomposes into a SDP of *sub*groups, but this is not the same.

Comment: $G \rtimes_\phi H$ is abelian iff $\phi: H \to Aut(G)$ is trivial so you are essentially asking what are the abelian groups $G$, $H$ such that there exists a nontrivial homomorphism $H \to Aut(G)$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis The existence of such a homomorphism is assumed. But just existence tells us nothing about what the SDP actually is, no?

Comment: Each such morphism yields a semidirect product. You are asking what groups are split extensions of abelian groups by abelian groups; clealy they must be metabelian, but beyond that I would be surprised if you could have any better description. Plenty of special situations based on the orders of the groups, but beyond that, this seems like it would be way too broad for a pat answer.

Comment: Reasonable restriction to rule it out: nonsolvable, or solvable of length at least $3$. Equivalently: commutator subgroup is not abelian.

Comment: I am completely unsure what you are asking. In a comment you said "The existence of such a homomorphism is assumed. But just existence tells us nothing about what the SDP actually is". I have no idea what you mean by that. If you are given $G$, $H$ and the homomorphism, then the SDP is defined and you know exactly what it is. But if you are given $G$ and $H$ and not told what the homomorphism is, then there will usually be several possibilities for the SDP. But all that seems obvious. Any answer to "which groups are semidirect products?" will be tautological.

Comment: @DerekHolt I assume the SDP is taken w.r.t. a nontrivial homomorphism, since this is not an interesting case. This is what I mean by 'nontrivial semidirect product.' Is that a poor way to phrase it? When I said "but just existence..." I was referring to the fact that if we know nothing specific about $G$ and $H$ nor the homomorphism, we know nothing specific about their SDP. This is in reply to Giorgos Giapitzaki's comment...

Comment: @DerekHolt ...whom says that we just need to know which groups have nontrivial $H \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. But suppose we did; simply knowing there exist nontrivial homs does not specify the SDP. We need to know what the hom does.

Comment: OK, but I am not sure what sort answer you might be expecting to your main question. Most of the things that you can say, like any such group must be metabelian, seem obvious or tautological. What sort of thing would you regard as a useful answer?