# Obstruction of semidirect product from being a direct product?

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G$ and $H$ be (nonabelian) groups, and $\varphi: G\to \text{Aut}(H)$ be a homomorphism. This defines the semidirect product $H\rtimes_{\varphi} G$. I am wondering, what is the best way to characterise how 'far away' $H\rtimes_{\varphi} G$ is from being a direct product $H\times G$?

My attempt: The product in $H\rtimes_{\varphi} G$ is
$$(h_1,g_1)(h_2,g_2)=(h_1\varphi_{g_1}(h_2),g_1g_2)$$
for $h_i\in H$, $g_i\in G$. Then the semidirect product is the direct product if $\varphi_{g_1}(h_1)=h_1$ for all $g_1\in G$ and all $h_1\in H$. This is true in turn if $\text{ker}(\varphi)=G$. Since $\text{ker}(\varphi)\triangleleft G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, we could view the quotient $G/\text{ker}(\varphi)$ as an 'obstruction group' of $H\rtimes_{\varphi} G$ being isomorphic to $H\times G$.

Question: Is there a better way to characterise the deviation from $\rtimes_\varphi$ being $\times$ (such as group cohomology), or can one make a similar statement without knowing the specific form of $\varphi$?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148558/discussion-on-question-by-el-rafu-obstruction-of-semidirect-product-from-being-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The group $G/\ker(\varphi)$ is not a good measure, because it depends on the  representation of the resulting group  and not on whether it is a direct product or not. As noted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/425065/742), if $H$ is nonabelian, $Z(H)=1$, and $f\colon H\to  \mathrm{Inn}(H)$ is a morphism, then the resulting semidirect product $H\rtimes_f H$ is actually isomorphic to the direct product $H\times H$. So you can have $\ker(\varphi)$ trivial, and yet have a direct product anyway.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin It doesn't measure if $H \rtimes_\varphi G \cong H \times G$ but it does measure if the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow H \rightarrow H \rtimes_\varphi G \rightarrow G \rightarrow 0$ splits. Therefore, it measures wether or not  $H \rtimes_\varphi G \cong H \times G$ "compatibly with this exact sequence".

Comment: To know if $H \rtimes_\varphi G \cong H \times G$ without carring about the exact sequence (and by extension about the way $H \rtimes_\varphi G$ is built), I see no other solution than finding a way to measure if two random groups $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic or not, like the greatest integer $n$ such that there exists a group $C$ of cardinality $n$ that injects in both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Cactus Does this short exact sequence not split for any semi-direct product?

Comment: Sorry, I have been inacurate. An exact sequence splits on the right if and only if it comes from a semi-direct product (and the left splitting is obviously the second variable projection). And it splits on the left if and only if it comes from a direct product. The equivalence of both spittings is only true in abelian categories.

Comment: Right. Does the question simplify if say $H$ is abelian?